# Getting the last value of a column and displaying it in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the last value of a column and display it throughout in another column. Below is a sample of the data that we have now.

```html
DT                             ETB_DT
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 04:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 08:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 12:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 16:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 20:00:00.0000000

No_of_records  cumulative
22               22
41               63
86               149
65               214
25               239
```

I am trying to get another column called total that shows the last value of cumulative throughout. Below is my desired output.

```html
DT                             ETB_DT
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 04:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 08:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 12:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 16:00:00.0000000
Friday 00:00:00.0000000 Friday 20:00:00.0000000

No_of_records  cumulative   total
22               22      239
41               63      239
86               149     239
65               214     239
25               239     239
```

Do you have any ideas? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simpler than your other question:

```
Select DT, ETB_DT, No_of_records
       sum(No_of_records) over () as total
From withoutcumulative4
Order by DT;
```

When you leave out the `order by`, you get the total sum over all the records (or for a portion if you had `partition by`).

Comment: Thank you so much!